# In situations where we have entropy decrease, are we violating second law?

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy

When we heat a material and this heat solidifies it (eg. when we cook an egg), isn't that decrease in entropy? when we have an endothermic reaction that produces larger molecules (synthesis), don't we have decrease in entropy?

Answer (score 1):

No, because the second law only applies to *isolated* systems.

Take, as an example, placing water into a freezer. When the water crystallises, its entropy decreases. However, the working of the freezer generates much more entropy. So when you consider the entire system (water+freezer+environment) collectively, the total entropy *increases* in accordance with the second law.